# Verb + ing after to

Tags: grammar

I notice too many people used `to + verb(ing)`, I read that after `to` the verb must be in the infinitive form.
Examples:

> 21 Steps **to Making** an Oscar Movie

My Correction:

> 21 steps **to make** an Oscar Movie

2.

> But there has to be more **to learning** than that!

My correction:

> But there has to be more to learn than that!

My question is:
Are these examples of `to + verb(ing)` are correct? or am I right about the corrections?

Comment: (1) If you look up "steps to making", "steps to understanding" etc you will see that this construction is commonly used. While in my opinion still more verby than the classical gerund (though 'steps to the making of' is also available), this is not as verby as 'steps to make'. // (2) Your second alternative has a different meaning. (a') 'But there has to be more to the process of learning than that!' ('learning' certainly a gerund in the original here) // (b')  'But there has to be more than that that needs to be learned!'

Comment: I'm so sorry, I didn't understand a thing! :(. If it doesn't annoying, can you please write a detailed answer about gerund, when to use it, why these use cases are correct? Because, I'm reading a book about grammar, and they said that, you must use an infinitive verb after to? I'm just more confused right now!

Comment: No; there are hundreds of questions and answers about gerunds (including whether or not the term should be used) on ELU already. Essentially, there are two _to_'s, and the grammar is speaking about the **infinitive marker** (To err is human / I'm going to leave / It's important to realise ...) rather than the preposition or multi-word-verb-particle (I'm going to London / She's devoted to John/singing/singing ballads / He's taken to sleeping in a hammock).